# 415 Error in Preflight Request using axios in React Js

Tags: reactjs

Getting 415 unsupported media type for Request Method as OPTIONS.
How to send the Content Type in the preflight request using axios

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass headers in axios config. Check the documentation here. [Axios config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

```
axios.get("endpoint", { headers: { "Content-Type": "Content-Type that you wanna pass here. (Eg. application/json)" } });
```